# How to printout a value a pointer is pointing at from an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

As in the title. I'm trying to print out a value that a pointer is pointing at but have no luck with it. The code below shows that Im assigning a pointer to a random position in an array .

```
//Assign a pointer to a random location in array 
int val = rand() % 6;
int* p = &a[val];
```

So far this is the only thing that works but it just prints out the location in memory, when I need the value `printf("%p", &p);` So again how can I print the value my pointer is pointing at ?

**Edit**: My array is declared like this `int a[6];` and im filling it like this:

```
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
{
    a[i] = pal_num % 10;
    pal_num /= 10;
}
```

Where pal_num is a 6 digit number

**Edit2:** Calling the function `print_status`

```
while (!is_pal(a))
{
    if (!is_pal(a))
    {
        print_status(a, num_mov, p);
        ask_for_command(p, num_mov);
    }
```

Comment: has your array have at least size of 6?

Comment: How is `a` defined, BTW?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: I've put some additional code. If that is still not clear please ask for more. Also the `printf` is in a function which goes as follows : `void print_status(int a[], int* p, int num_mov)`

Comment: And how does the function `print_status()` get called?

Comment: @alk I've added an edit number 2 which shows the call

Comment: This `print_status(a, num_mov, p);` does not seem to fit this `void print_status(int a[], int* p, int num_mov)`.

Comment: @alk OMG I should have `print_status(a,p,num_mov)` ARGH such an easy mistake :(. Thank you @alk . How do I close the question? Im new on this site.

Comment: The compiler should have yelled at you parsing this code. Bump up the warning level and take warnings serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereference the pointer, like so:

```
printf("%d", *p);
```

Operator `*` on pointers is the opposite of operator `&`.

Comment: I'm getting an exception thrown that looks like this when I try your answer:Exception thrown at 0x01151A56 in pointers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: @Username Is the value in `p` valid? Are you sure you get a correct pointer, because the crash message says that you're dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: @Username: What do you for `printf("%p", (void*)p);` though?

Comment: @alk If I do what you have done, It prints 000000 and then breaks.